# Kotlin add carriage return into multiline string

Tags: kotlin, multiline, multilinestring

In Kotlin, when I build a multiline string like this:

```
value expected = """
                |digraph Test {
                |${'\t'}Empty1;
                |${'\t'}Empty2;
                |}
                |""".trimMargin()
```

I see that the string lacks carriage return characters (ASCII code 13) when I output it via:

```
println("Expected bytes")
println(expected.toByteArray().contentToString())
```

Output:

```
Expected bytes
[100, 105, 103, 114, 97, 112, 104, 32, 84, 101, 115, 116, 32, 123, 10, 9, 69, 109, 112, 116, 121, 49, 59, 10, 9, 69, 109, 112, 116, 121, 50, 59, 10, 125, 10]
```

When some code I'm trying to unit test builds the same String via a `PrintWriter` it delineates lines via the `lineSeparator` property:

```
/* 
 * Line separator string.  This is the value of the line.separator
 * property at the moment that the stream was created.
 */
```

So I end up with a string which *looks* the same in output, but is composed of different bytes and thus is not equal:

```
Actual bytes
[100, 105, 103, 114, 97, 112, 104, 32, 84, 101, 115, 116, 32, 123, 13, 10, 9, 69, 109, 112, 116, 121, 49, 59, 13, 10, 9, 69, 109, 112, 116, 121, 50, 59, 13, 10, 125, 13, 10]
```

Is there a better way to address this *during string declaration* than splitting my multiline string into concatenated stringlets which can each be suffixed with `char(13)`?

Alternately, I'd like to do something like:

```
value expected = """
                |digraph Test {
                |${'\t'}Empty1;
                |${'\t'}Empty2;
                |}
                |""".trimMargin().useLineSeparator(System.getProperty("line.separator"))
```

or `.replaceAll()` or such.

Does any standard method exist, or should I add my own extension function to String?

Comment: What OS are you running on?

Comment: Windows. It must be.

Comment: Just do `.replace("\n", "\r\n")`

Comment: It may be better to read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline Especially the first table part.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Kotlin multiline strings are always compiled into string literals which use \n as the line separator. If you need to have the platform-dependent line separator, you can do `replace("\n", System.getProperty("line.separator"))`.

As of Kotlin 1.2, there is no standard library method for this, so you should define your own extension function if you're using this frequently.

Answer (score 42):

This did the trick.

```
    System.lineSeparator()
```